# iOS : Bypass the splash screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, splash-screen

Just for thought, Can we bypass the `Splash-Screen` of iPhone/iPad app while developing the app?
Actually, I need app without Splash-screen, but If I haven't set image for Splash in X-code, it displays as black screen after launch, I want to override this.

Comment: @DCMaxxx is right. When you launch the Facebook app, you see a basic outline of the Newsfeed. It's not the app, but a splashscreen image.

Answer (score 8):

Splash image or Launch images are mandatory, as per [HIG guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html).

> You must provide at least one launch image. Typically, an iPhone app includes at least one launch image in portrait orientation; an iPad app includes at least one launch image in portrait orientation and at least one launch image in landscape orientation.

Application submitted for review without splash screen will not be accepted by Apple.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible. The splash screen is displayed while your app get's loaded into memory. Hence, you should provide a splash screen to make the loading process look better.

Use the splash screen to your advantage and show your logo/information while the app loads.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [Human Interface Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html), you'll see that a launch image is mandatory.

However, you can *fake* not having it by using the same image as your first screen (which is exactly what Apple wants you to do - see guidelines once again).

Answer (score 0):

Universal apps must provide launch images for both the iPhone and iPad idioms.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12

To let the system know that your app supports the iPhone 5 screen size, include a properly named launch image in your app’s bundle. At runtime, the system looks for a launch image whose name contains the -568h modifier. If such an image is present, the system assumes that your app supports the iPhone 5 explicitly and runs it in fullscreen mode. If such an image is not present, the system runs your app with black bars above and below your app’s content on devices with the larger screen; it also reports the screen size of your app as 320 by 480 points so that your app’s screen-based calculations continue to be correct.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html